# Quotient Group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

I know this a very basic question, but I'm struggling to grasp the meaning of the result:

$$
\color{red}{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{[0],[1]\} } \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

From the notes I'm following if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $x,y\in G$, $x$ is said to be equivalent to $y$ ($x\sim y$) if

$$
x - y \in H
$$

**First Question** What is the meaning of the operator '$-$'? Should I interpret $-y$ as the inverse of $y$?

Now, for any two even numbers  $2n - 2m = 2(n - m)\in 2\mathbb{Z}$, moreover $[2m] = [2n] = [0]$. Same applies for odd numbers. So this means that the equivalence class $[0]$ should belong to the quotient group.

**Second Question** If I operate an even and odd number I get something that does not belong to $2\mathbb{Z}$, how do I get the class $[1]$ in Eq. \ref{1}?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, one nice little observation: $[0]=2\mathbb Z$, $[1]=1+2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: You are right about the first question and for the second, just notice that $2n + (2m+1) = 2(m+n) + 1$, wat is exactly $1$ in $\mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Just a little point: you are right about $-$, it starts off denoting the inverse as in $-y$, but then we abuse the notation a little and write $x-y$ for $x+(-y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed, you have two classes: the one of even numbers, $[0]$ and the one of odd numbers, $[1]$.

The answer to your first question is yes.

In the answer to the second question, that's precisely how you get something in $[1]$ since the sum of an even number with an odd one is odd.